# Websocket server on a UWP app

Tags: javascript, cordova, websocket, uwp

I'm trying to implement a WebSocket server on my UWP app. Something similar to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-websocket-server) plugin for Android and iOS, or [Chrome socket server](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/sockets_tcpServer). I've looked into the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app samples for [WebSockets](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebSocket), but the way I understand it, it can be used as a Client side, while the Server is run separately using a PowerShell script.

My app is built with HTML and Javascript (AngularJS), compiled with Cordova framework and I wanted a WebSocket Server to run on it so that outside clients would be able to send commands to the app.

Is there any such way (or similar to it) to do this (to receive commands via TCP, etc)?

Comment: This is a bit old, but i'm looking to it too.